# Jupyter Lab on EC2 instance not reachable through web browser after stopping and restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-lab

I have setup an AWS EC2 instance and setup Miniconda and JupyterLab on it, following [this tutorial](https://dataschool.com/data-modeling-101/running-jupyter-notebook-on-an-ec2-server/).

I can access it through the terminal using the PEM file and launch the `jupyter lab` command. But when I try to reach the provided address through my web browser, I get a `The connection has timed out: The server at ec2-******.*******.compute.amazonaws.com is taking too long to respond` error.

How do I solve this?

**Edit 1**

The security inbound rules:

[image: inbound-rules]

**Edit 2**

The page when I try to reach it:

[image: firefox]

**Edit 3**

Output of `netstat -nat`:

[image]

**Edit 4**

Live output of command `jupyter lab`:

[image]

Comment: Are you accessing URL with correct port? like here
https://(your AWS public URL):8888/

Comment: Yup I did this @Gaurav

Comment: Are you sure there is a running process listening on port 8888? Have you verified this with `netstat -nat`? You should see something similar to `0.0.0.0:8888` with a `LISTEN` state.

Comment: I put in the edit the relevant outputs of the commands you suggested.

Comment: I do have the same problem, still trying to figure out why I can't connect to it :(

Answer (score 0):

You probably have only port 22 opened in Security Groups which allows SSH. Open port 80 for HTTP or 443 for HTTPS.